# Render a wireframe animation where only half of the mesh has wireframe

Tags: animation, wireframe

How can i render a wireframe on an animated rotating mesh, where only 
the right side of the camera view is shown in wireframe, but the other half shows the mesh withouth it.

Only the parts of the mesh that are on the right half of the screen should be in wireframe, but when the animation rotates the mesh, the faces that where rendered in wireframe should become normal again (when they leave the "wireframe" area.).

Edit: When the mesh is not rotating, i could create a vertex group and apply the wireframe modifier to the parts i want to be wireframe, but i don't know how to do this when the mesh rotates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]I think that the only easy way to achieve the result is to render the animation two times: one showing wireframe and one normal; then use a video editing tool (even Blender itself) to show on the left part of the screen the normal render and on the right the wireframe one.

Comment: We have done it with 2 render layers and with a (box mask)->(blur) in the compositor.